# How many triplets $\left(m,n,p\right)$ where $p$ is a prime satisfy $2^mp^2+1=n^5$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

How many triples $\left(m,n,p\right)$ where $p$ is a prime satisfy $2^mp^2+1=n^5$?

Found one of the solutions for $\left(m,n,p\right)$ to be $\left(1,3,11\right)$ by analysis without using modular arithmetic. How should I attempt this problem? Thanks

Comment: Please avoid phrases as "now I want it answered"

Comment: Are we to assume $m,n,p \in \Bbb Z$?

Comment: I am not sure whether I changed the intent of the question. Is $p=2$ (and $m=0$) allowed as well ?

Comment: @Peter 2^0=1, so that doesnt work.

Comment: @RhysHughes I know, but nevertheless it could be allowed although in this case there is no solution.

Comment: Hi all, What if all numbers are positive integers?

Comment: *"I'm linking it here to prevent creating a duplicate"* - But it is still a duplicate; you're literally reposting the same question. I would suggest you make this into a self-contained question, so that the (poor) original can be deleted.

Comment: Okay will do :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that if $(m,n,p)$ is a solution, then
$$2^mp^2=n^5-1=(n-1)(n^4+n^3+n^2+n+1).$$
In particular $n-1$ divides $2^mp^2$, so $n=2^ap^b+1$ for some $a\leq m$ and $b\leq2$. Plugging this in yields
$$2^mp^2+1=n^5=\left(2^ap^b\right)^5+5\left(2^ap^b\right)^4+10\left(2^ap^b\right)^3+10\left(2^ap^b\right)^2+5\left(2^ap^b\right)+1,$$
and a bit of rearranging shows that
$$2^{m-a}p^{2-b}=\left(2^ap^b\right)^4+5\left(2^ap^b\right)^3+10\left(2^ap^b\right)^2+10\left(2^ap^b\right)+5.$$
The right hand side is odd so $m=a$ and $p>2$, and we are left with
$$p^{2-b}=2^{4m}p^{4b}+5\cdot2^{3m}p^{3b}+5\cdot2^{2m+1}p^{2b}+5\cdot2^{m+1}p^b+5.$$
From this it is not hard to see that $b=0$, so $n=2^m+1$. This leaves you with solving
$$p^2=\frac{(2^m+1)^5-1}{2^m}=16^m+5\cdot8^m+10\cdot4^m+10\cdot2^m+5.$$
For $m>1$ the right hand side is congruent to $5$ mod $8$ and hence not a square, so the only solution is $(m,n,p)=(1,3,11)$.

Comment: Care to explain the downvotes?

Comment: Hey thank you for your help Servaes. You made an interesting point but I don't understand what to do next. Can you kindly help with the intuition?

Comment: And I think that b is always 2

Comment: There are many ways to go; I added one way to finish. If you would like more details, let me know.

Comment: That was amazing! From the last answer, do we have to use trial and error in order to find the answers?

Comment: Oh. $\left(1,11,3\right)$ is a solution though

Comment: I think you mean $(1,3,11)$? I see I made a typo in my last line. Let me rewrite.